# Dynamic model name for ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using angularjs with django. In my html page, I am doing the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="loc in locations" ng-init="locIndex = $index" ng-show="tab===1">
   Id: {[{loc[0]}]}
   Location Name: {[{loc[1]}]
</div>
```

Now, what I am interested in doing is:

```
<div ng-repeat="loc in locations" ng-show="tab===1">
   Id: {[{loc[0]}]}
   Location Name: {[{loc[1]}]
</div>
<div ng-repeat="cloc in childLocation{[{loc[0]}]}">
   Child Id:{[{loc[0]}]}
   Child Location Name: {[{loc[1]}]
</div>
```

In app.js, i will initialize the childlocations when the user will click the parent location

```
$scope.getChildLocations=function(locationId){
        $http({
            method: "get",
                url: '/get_child_locations?locationId='+locationId,
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                  childLocation='childLocation'+location
                  $scope.childLocation=data;
            });
    }
```

Is it possible to do this. If yes, how as i am getting an error in this..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because `loc` is not defined in your second `ng-repeat` since it is not nested.

Try:

```
<div ng-repeat="loc in locations" ng-show="tab===1">
    Id: {[{loc[0]}]}
    Location Name: {[{loc[1]}]
    <div ng-repeat="cloc in childLocation{[{loc[0]}]}">
        Child Id:{[{loc[0]}]}
        Child Location Name: {[{loc[1]}]
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is actually 
<div ng-repeat="cloc in childLocation{[{loc[0]}]}">
        Child Id:{[{cloc[0]}]}
        Child Location Name: {[{cloc[1]}]
    </div> 
Sorry for the typos

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: Pls tell me if its possible to create a ng-repeat iterator by appending $index and then how can i access that var in app.js to assign value to it